# Flagging history should include comment flags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, flag-history

Whenever I tag a comment, I haven't got the faintest idea if someone has reacted on it or not.

Once, it took two days before a comment I flagged was deleted. In the meantime, I actually don't know if the moderators agree with my flagging or think I'm wrong.

I like the flagging history for questions and answers and believe that the flagging weight only should count for these.

But I'd like to be able to see somehow, what response/reaction there is to my comment flags (in the same way like the flagging history, maybe). This could improve my flagging.

And of course, not only mine, but also others.

Comment: Well, at least now have the absolute count to check *if* they were marked as helpful or not.

Comment: +1, I was quite surprised how low my helpful count was on comment flags, especially compared to the other kinds of flags. I'd like to see which ones were were declined to improve them.

Comment: +1 from me as well. Even the red bar at the top showing *"Your flag was deemed as helpful/was declined"* would be enough; maybe something else where the mod has the ability to add a short explanation of why (not mandatory and anonymous) but I don't mind if only the red-bar-thing is implemented.

Comment: I wonder if the information is deliberately hidden though to avoid revealing too many details about the secret "A single flag from a user can delete some comments" heuristics.

Comment: +1 - i might also ask to see the moderator's name in the decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature has been implemented.

Comment: Do you know, when exactly it was implemented? (Can't find any sources about it). And why wasn't this request tagged with [status-completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) then?

Comment: @Idolon In the right pane of the flagging history, a simple overview of all flags are displayed. Also for the comments; although you can't see the specifics, this is better than nothing.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. I just wonder when it was implemented (as [Recent feature changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/158912) page is silent about that).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you remember where you have raised comment flags recently, it is already possible to find out the responses to your flags.

Picture this scenario: Your have flagged three comments, and you come back the next day and your flagging summary says

> 3 comments flagged
>   1 deemed helpful
>   1 declined

Then check the places where you had flagged comments:

- If the comment disappeared, your flag was (most likely) deemed helpful.
- If the comment is still there, but there is **no flag icon** when you hover over it, your flag is still pending for review.
- If the comment is still there and the flag icon is shown on hover, your flag has been declined.