# Suggested cleanup and feature for user's "flagging history" page

Tags: feature-request, flags, profile-page, moderation, flag-history

Hooray! We've got our flagging history page with decision records and counts. It's a great start and I think it really does help, but I have a couple tweaks to propose.

Atop similar requests (ex. [Flagging history should include comment flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120617/flagging-history-should-include-comment-flags)) I think the following changes would improve readability and usefulness.

- Comment Flag decisions be displayed
- Flag decision records be cleaned up something like this below:

  *"Collapsed" - default, two-line summary*

  ```
  [17] Well-Liked Question Title          flagged 2012-02-11 10:22pm
     Declined                           decided 2012-02-14 07:58am 
     ...more...
  [3]  Some Other Question Asked          flagged 2009-11-28 04:12pm
     Approved                           decided 2009-11-28 04:15pm 
     ...more...
  ```

  *"Expanded" clicking `...more...` to something like this:*

  ```
  [3]  Some Other Question Asked          flagged 2009-11-28 04:12pm
     Approved                           decided 2009-11-28 04:15pm 
     Flagged {TYPE} by Bob Johnson as {REASON}
     "user text snippet here... Bob is such a jerk, I'm serious,  
      he's always so chatty and I heard he even go fire from his 
      job for exposing himself. He thinks he knows everything."
  ```

**{TYPE}** = Comment, Question, Answer...

**{REASON}** = Off-Topic, Not a Question, etc...

---

*EDIT: The layouts can be implemented and is proposed with or without the display of Comment Flags.*

Comment: I don't want to know which moderator declined or approved. I can imagine the moderators won't be too keen on publishing that information either.

Comment: @DanielFischer You and Nick are right. The initial "moderator name" has been entirely removed from the proposal. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The layouts improvements are mostly all predicated on the first two bits:

> - Comment Flag decisions be displayed
> - Deciding Moderator's name be listed next to the decision for both flag types.

For the first, we don't store this data...comment flags just aren't as important as posts, that's how it is.  For the second: no.  We *very* consciously don't display this information to users, no net good can result from doing so.

That being said, sure, the page could use some layout love...it just hasn't been a priority.  To be honest, knowing what we do now, we wouldn't have ever exposed that page to users.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I understand and agree about the "moderator name" - it's been removed from question. The Comment Flags are counted toward "Helpful Flags" and I'm sure logged if flagged offensive, so some part of the data is persisted - are you sure such a feature isn't feasible?

Comment: The layouts however are not predicated by the bits. In fact they would be excellent presentation enhancements without any changes to what is tracked or logged.

Comment: "knowing what we do now, we wouldn't have ever exposed that page to users" - out of curiosity, what is it that you now know which makes it a bad idea?

Comment: "we wouldn't have ever exposed that page to users." - sometimes a little secret totalitarianism is rather handy. :)

Comment: @DanielFischer Ever looked at questions tagged [tag:flag-weight]?

Comment: @yoda At some. I don't see the connection with the 'Flagging summary' page. I can see that exposing flag-weight may have been a bad idea, but that's not how I read the quoted passage - did I misread it?