# Flag counters not shown although I had flagged some comments

Tags: bug, flags, profile-page, meta, comment-flags

I had flagged some comments as obsolete (here on meta), but the flagging history page in my profile (for meta) is still completely empty. I know that comment flags are not listed individually, so – as expected – the main list below *"Flagging Summary"* is empty. (I have not yet flagged any questions or answers.)

Still, I would have expected that the flag counters (including the [comment flag counter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120617/191131)) are shown on the right-hand page border below *"Your flagging history"*. Currently, there are no counters at all.

The flagging history page is the same as in the screen shot in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122424/191131), but I don't think that I am experiencing exactly the same problem: my main profile page says "helpful flags 0".

The comments to [the above question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122424/191131) say that the discrepancy could be caused because the flagged comments have been deleted in the meantime. This is not the case – I remember which ones they were, and they are still both there. However I noticed that the flag icon (when you hover over the comment) re-appeared for one of them. Does this mean that the obsolete flag for that one comment has already been processed (and rejected) by an operator?

Am I assuming something wrong? Or is this a bug in the system? Possibly that the counters are only shown once I have at least one non-comment flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Gaffi I could verify the hypothesis: *As long as a user hasn't flagged any questions or answers, the flag counters are not shown at all.*

Now that I have one flagged answer ("1 moderator attention flags, 1 waiting for review"), the flag counters, including comment flag counters, are shown on my flagging summary page.

---

And another observation: Comments you have flagged don't show the flag icon (on hover) while they are pending for review. If the flag icon comes back, the comment flag has been declined.

Comment: This is a bug, isn't it?

Comment: Sounds like it might be, yes. But then again, some dev may know better and can explain why this is the way it is.

Comment: ... and now I know that I have raised 4 comment flags so far, and all of them were rejected :-(  Thinking about it, I remember that I once was surprised to see that I had not flagged one comment, but actually I had flagged it and the flag was rejected. So I did flag the same comment twice. Now I feel stupid...

Comment: Exactly why I gave the +1. :-) I think most users won't run into this issue, but it can still happen.

Comment: Now, while I did up-vote this answer, I'm starting to think this should not be the *accepted* answer. You've highlighted the behavior, but I still think that's wrong and this is a bug. That is, unless someone wants to [meta-tag:status-bydesign] this...?

Comment: Are there any special rules for accepting answers on open bugs on meta? According to the normal rules, accepting an answer makes sense: In my opinion, the question doesn't need further answers because we have the root cause identified.

Comment: I personally would un-accept this until some sort of official status/response to the bug itself has been posted. As a question with an accepted answer, it may appear that the issue has been resolved, when really it hasn't been. Here, you've merely identified the (possibly) root problem.

Answer (score 4):

The flagging history only shows your flags (with links/status) on Questions and Answers. Comment detail is left only as a count on the right-hand panel, but no links to those questions are provided.

Also, to relate to the answers/comments in one of your links, there may be a caching issue. Wait a bit to see if those counts do appear later.

[This FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85151/179372) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/179372) don't directly answer your question, but it may be helpful to look at anyway.

---

I'm guessing, based on your update, that waiting it out did not clear up the problem? I don't have the answer to that directly, but perhaps you could seek out a particularly bad question or answer and flag it. If this changes the page, then it appears your hypothesis may be correct.

Are you aware if those comments still exist or have they been deleted? It may also be that you need a comment flag deemed helpful first, but that might be harder for you to track down.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is still there, so probably not a caching issues. Any proposals on bad meta question or answer I could flag?

Comment: @oberlies See my new answer. :-)