# Flag history not populating in beta site

Tags: support, flag-history

I had raised a spam flag the other day on [Freelancing.SE](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com) on a question, which was marked as helpful. My user profile page correctly shows one helpful flag (as it was my first flag).

However, when I navigated to my [flag summary](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/9), I was greeted with a blank flag summary, as shown below:

[image]

I'm trying to think of situations why this may be the case; is the display of flagging history driven off of normal flags (i.e., not spam/offensive)?

Both of these related questions ([this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122424/175498) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145400/175498)) don't appear to be duplicates, since they deal with comments; this spam flag had been thrown on a question.

Comment: I had the same thing on Chemistry.SE

Comment: Drat, @animuson. That _is_ an exact duplicate. I'll go ahead and place a bounty on that one.